# Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am trying to filter a dataframe as:

```
a= a[~(b['var1'].isin(c['var2']))]
```

but get the following error:

```
"Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

I understand that the statement:

```
print(~(b['var1'].isin(c['var2'])) [:10])
```

is returning a series that is boolean masked which may not be acceptable. So, I tried to use loc as:

```
a= a.loc[:, ~(b['var1'].isin(c['var2']))]
```

but I am getting the same error. What am I missing here? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `a,b,c` are 3 different DataFrames?

Comment: yes, they are three different dataframes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error means there are different index of `a` and of mask created with `isin`, it means different index of `b`.

```
mask = ~(b['var1'].isin(c['var2']))
```

So possible solution is change index by `a.index` and for not matched values add `False`s:

```
a[mask.reindex(a.index, fill_value=False)]
```

Or:

```
a[~(b['var1'].reindex(a.index, fill_value=False).isin(c['var2']))]
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. And makes sense. I was wondering would it be better to write this code more intuitively (in a traditional data handling sense) as some kind of a join/merge perhaps?

Comment: @flying_fluid_four - yes, another idea is created new DaTaframe from `a, b` like `df = a.join(b['var1'])` and then filter `a[~(df['var1'].isin(c['var2']))]`

Comment: @flying_fluid_four - But necessary not misisng values in `c['var2']`, because differnece `b['var1']` and `df['var1']` is with missing values for unmatched index.